# Joint PMF of X and Y

Tags: probability

Question: find the constant C

$$\displaystyle f(x,y)=\frac{C}{x!(y-x)!},y=0, 1, 2...; x=0,1,...y$$

How do I evaluate C? I've seen problems using Maclaurin series but I have no clue what to do with this one.

Comment: Think in terms of binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set it in a way so:
$$
\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}\sum_{x=0}^{y}f(x,y) = 1
$$
That way, you need to figure out how much is the sum:
$$
\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}\sum_{x=0}^{y}\frac1{x!(y-x)!}=\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}\sum_{x=0}^{y}\frac{\frac{y!}{x!(y-x)!}}{y!}=\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}\sum_{x=0}^{y}\frac{\left(    \begin{matrix}
    y\\
    x
    \end{matrix}\right)}{y!}=\sum_{x=0}^{y}\frac{2^y}{y!}=e^2
$$
In the last step, we realise that the sum is the Taylor serie of $e^z$. This means that if you set $C=e^{-2}$, the first equation is satisfied. So the answer is: $C=e^{-2}$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{y=0}^\infty \sum_{x=0}^y \frac{1}{x!(y-x)!} &=
\sum_{x=0}^\infty  \sum_{y=x}^\infty \frac{1}{x!(y-x)!}  &\text{(order of summation doesn't matter)}\\
&= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x!} \sum_{z=0}^\infty \frac{1}{z!} &(\text{substitute with $z=y-x$}) \\
&= \big(\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{1}{x!} \big)^2 \\
&= e^2
\end{align*}
Thus $C=e^{-2}$

Answer (score 0):

$$1 = \sum_{y=0}^{\infty} \sum_{x=0}^{y}f(x,y) = \sum_{y=0}^{\infty} \sum_{x=0}^{y} \frac{C}{x! (y-x)!} = C.\sum_{y=0}^{\infty} \sum_{x=0}^y \frac{y!}{x!(y-x)!y!} = C.\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^y}{y!} = C.e^2$$

hence we have that $$C = \frac{1}{e^2}$$